# Is there a convenience function to compute the R^2 for GLM.jl's lm?

Tags: julia, linear-regression

```
using RDatasets
cars = dataset("datasets", "cars")
m1 = lm(@formula(Dist~Speed), cars)
```

Now how do I extract the R^2 of `m1`? I tried `summary(m1)` and it didn't contain the information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `r2` or `r²` function (two names point at the same function).

For adjusted R^2 you can use `adjr2` or `adjr²` function.